# Comparisons of DotNetNuke with other CMS's/Web Application Frameworks such as WordPress or CodeIgniter

Tags: wordpress, drupal, codeigniter, joomla, dotnetnuke

I have never used DotNetNuke before. I'm thinking about giving it a try to help me build websites, and I'd like to hear from other developers who are in a position to compare DotNetNuke with other CMS's/Web Application Frameworks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used both DNN and Drupal to build fairly large, content-based sites.  My focus is more on the production side... UI/themeing, module configuration, etc.  I'm sold on Drupal, but there may be other choices that meet your needs just as well.  I just happened to work with both systems in recent months.

Drupal's core taxonomy module gives you the benefit of creating a relationship between different kinds of content.  If you have "article" and "video" content types, you can easily display data from both types based on the shared taxonomy terms.  This is huge and something DNN lacks.

Drupal's hook system is also a big benefit when building your own modules or creating "sub-modules" to alter or add to the default functionality of an existing module.  This allows you to customize functionality or take advantage of another module's functionality as your application runs. If you purchase a module for DNN, you will have to alter the module if it doesn't meet your needs. Once you do this, you will need to update it each time there's a new release that you would like to take advantage of.  DNN modules seem to be more stand-alone solutions.  For example, if a DNN module has a rating system, it's only a part of that solution.  With Drupal, I can use the "5 Star" rating module in my forums, my blogs, my articles, my videos, etc.  There's central configuration for it and I only theme it once.

The themeing layer in Drupal also gives you a large amount of flexibility in that process.  My frustration with themeing DNN sites was that I was stuck working with the markup the developer used, with no option for altering the output without hacking the module. With theme hooks and function overrides, I can change the output from those modules to meet my needs (not completely sometimes, but enough), without touching the module code itself.

The biggest problem I had with DNN modules, including some of the most popular, was just a lack of documentation or discussions available for how to achieve your goal.  While Drupal's forums can be hard to navigate and you might not always find the answer you are looking for, there are many outlets for gathering information.  Honestly, using DNN made me appreciate the community approach of Drupal more.

I was left feeling that DNN would be fine for building sites with more basic needs.  But for that, I would still choose something like WordPress or Joomla, considering they have much larger user bases and, in my opinion, are more sophisticated.

Hope this helps you some.

Answer (score 4):

DNN is a pretty good .NET solution for CMS. If you want more flexibility, I would look at SiteFinity for .NET CMS systems. This is a very flexible and elegant CMS for .NET

If you venture out of .NET and want to look at PHP solutions, then DRUPAL, JOOMLA, and WORDPRESS are best solutions. Some comments about each:

1. WORDPRESS - Is the simplest and most elegant CMS to work with. Originally a blogging software, it has a super-easy user interface, although that also reads as more limited power and features. It's excellent for content driven websites and templates are easily built.
2. DRUPAL - Is very flexible and configurable, but I find it more complicated than the others. The Admin interface requires more programming knowledge to pull off and adding components and extras is a little more complicated. But, DRUPAL has been proven in the business and government world as a secure and reliable CMS.
3. JOOMLA - Is my personal favorite. It is also very powerful and I prefer the Admin. interface. Joomla allows for much flexibility and has the most user created modules and plug-ins out there. You have to invent near nothing with this one. I am biased in favor of Joomla, because I use it the most. That said, it has limiting factors against DRUPAL, such as user security features. But this is being fixed in the next upgrade.

Hope that helps as well.

Answer (score 3):

I have development experience using both DNN and Drupal to build content-rich websites.  My preference is Drupal for a number of reasons:

1. Development time-line was shorter; I was able to produce more in less time.
2. Drupal has a larger and more active developer community.  More resources are available to aid in development.
3. DNN is not actually a CMS.  It is only a framework; Drupal is a framework with a foundational CMS.
4. Drupal is easier to install.
5. DNN modules cost money; Drupal modules are free.

Actually, I put together some notes a while back when trying to understand the architectural differences between DNN and Drupal.  Found those notes, they are here:  [DNN versus Drupal](http://technologyfountain.com/DNNversusDrupal.doc).  Hope this is helpful.

I experienced a fairly high degree of frustration when working with DNN and I don't believe I am alone in that regard.  About a year ago, ASPdotnetStoreFront abandoned their involvement with DNN calling it a "disaster to work with".

I am curious to know what piqued your interest in DNN and if you have a specific website project in mind.  Regardless, I wish you success and I hope this helps.

Comment: Basically, i am looking for a free .NET CMS to help free up my time building websites rather than having to reinvent the wheel for various functionality. As an example, i need a CMS for this website: http://www.commonwealthsw.org that will allow my client to post news articles from a WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: Ah, well.  If you are looking for something that is .NET based, I can't offer much more insight into that.  I have heard a few people say Kentico is a better alternative to DNN, but I don't have any personal experience with Kentico.

Answer (score 1):

I worked in a .NET development shop utilizing Kentico CMS. I agree, it is feature rich and stable. The API and DB are documented well. Overall, it is a great CMS. There is a limited free version: http://www.kentico.com/freecms.aspx

I'm testing out DNN right now. So far, so good, but I think it depends a lot on what you are using it for. I've only been looking at it for 3 days, but so far I do find the documentation lacking or outdated.

Answer (score 1):

I evaluated many of the different Portal/CMS systems out there back in 2004 and DotNetNuke ended up being my choice and I've been very pleased with it, for everything but E-Commerce, ever since. DotNetNuke is endlessly extensible, easy to skin, easy for non-technical folks to update, has a great 3rd party eco-system, and the development team is very active and talented. There isn't a great Articles module in the core but there are several really good ones available from 3rd parties for a reasonable price.

I tried using Joomla a few years ago and hated it. Wordpress is good for a blog style site but doesn't have nearly the power or flexibility of something like DNN. I am intrigued by SiteFinity, Umbraco, and Kentico for sites where all that's really needed is a CMS, but not enough that I've bothered trying them over DNN.

Answer (score 0):

Another good .NET solution - from what I've read - is Umbraco.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Kentico CMS. It's commercial, but still affordable. In my experience from dozens of projects on both CMS, Kentico is much more feature-rich, stable and well documented.